# Preventing overriding and/or hiding base class function (C++ 11)

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I've wanted to prevent even the hiding of base class non-virtual function for a while since I learned C++, and I'm not sure if this would be ethical, but C++ 11 features gave me an idea. Suppose I have the following:

bases.h....

```
#ifndef baseexample_h
#define baseexample_h

#include <iostream>

class Base{
    public:  
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Base.foo()\n" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{ 
    public:
    void foo(){
        std::cout << "Derived.foo()\n" << std::endl;
    }   
};

#endif
```

and main.cpp...

```
#include "bases.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    Base base;
    Derived derived; 

    base.foo();
    derived.foo();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
};
```

for which the output is of course

```
Base.foo()

Derived.foo()
```

as the derived foo() function *hides* the base foo function. I want to prevent possible hiding, So my idea was to change the header file Base definition to:

```
//.....
class Base{
    public:  
    virtual void foo() final {
        std::cout << "Base.foo()\n" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base{ 
    public:
    void foo(){ //compile error
        std::cout << "Derived.foo()\n" << std::endl;
    }   
};
//......
```

Which seems to enforce what I want with a compiler error, prevention of overriding AND/OR hiding in c++, but my question is, is this *a good practice* since foo() was never a virtual function to begin with? Is there a downside to this since i'm kind of *abusing* the virtual keyword? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't even solve the problem completely. You can still hide the `foo` name, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/rbAO1x).

Comment: Then again, there actually isn't a problem.

Comment: Interesting... OK. Is *const* the only keyword that changes the prototype enough for this to happen? I might actually even want this behavior, I suppose.

Comment: @user27886 the name can be hidden by *anything* called `foo`, even a private data member. But concerning member functions, `final` would only prevent you from overriding `void foo()`. `const`, `volatile`, or arguments would result in hiding. `final` only prevents overriding, not hiding.

Comment: http://ideone.com/fK2p436 no.

Comment: @user27886: _Prototypes_ are not C++ but C, and they aren't what you think they are, which is _signatures_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that, yes, it's bad practice. You introduced polymorphism when you didn't want it, just to prevent name hiding.

But what's so bad about name hiding? Obviously, for whatever reason, the design of `Derived` desires to hide the function `foo` in its base class; that is what it does — perhaps it makes  its own call to `Base::foo` then performs some additional activity that is required within `Derived`.

**Trying to subvert that is bad enough; trying to do it by co-opting language features that you *don't want* is even worse.**

If you *really need* to call the base function, use `derived.Base::foo()`, but be aware that you are essentially breaking the API of the class `Derived`, which you should instead use as documented.

Comment: "Obviously, for whatever reason, the design of Derived desires to hide the function foo in its base class"  -  Not so obvious; it may be an accidentally similar choice in name or `foo` may be added to `Base` after `Derived` was written and then a simple mistake the compiler/IDE could ideally catch goes undetected until tests/QA.  I don't believe C++ has a solution to this problem, but it's a shame.