# Why is it not possible to define a non-virtual method as final in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Today I was pretty happy when I learned that C++11 now finally knowns the `final` keyword. With it you can easily define a whole class as *final* and even single virtual methods. But I wonder why this is not possible for non-virtual methods? Let's take this example:

```
class A {
public:
    void m1() { cout << "A::m1" << endl; };            
    virtual void m2() { cout << "A::m2" << endl; };      
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void m1() { cout << "B::m1" << endl; };
    virtual void m2() { cout << "B::m2" << endl; };
};
```

Here I can easily prevent `B` from overriding the virtual `m2` by declaring `A::m2` as final. I would like to do the same with `A::m1` so `B` can't hide `A:m1` with it's own implementation of the method. but the compiler doesn't accept the `final` keyword without `virtual`. And I wonder if there is a reason why C++11 doesn't allow this and if I misunderstood something completely. In my opinion it makes perfectly sense to define a non-virtual method as final because I didn't declare it as virtual because I don't want others to override/hide it anyway (Which I can now enforce with `final` but unfortunately only for virtual methods...)

I like class designs where everything except abstract methods are final. It looks like this means I have to declare all methods as `virtual` now to be able to do that. Is that a good idea or are there reasons against it? For older C++ versions I often read that is a bad idea to declare all methods as virtual. Or maybe there is a better way to prevent hiding non-virtual methods?

Comment: because non-virtual methods are final already. you can't override them, you can only hide them.

Comment: @Bryan Yes, you`re right, but that's still something I want to prevent. I changed the question to make this clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing overriding and/or hiding base class function (C++ 11)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641736/preventing-overriding-and-or-hiding-base-class-function-c-11)

Comment: There is no way to prevent function hiding in general. You can , in class B, put `using` declarations to inject any functions from A that you don't want to hide.

Comment: If there is no *technical* reason to protect a method/class from overriding with final simply don't do it. After the final keyword comes up I saw a lot of code with final in libraries. And we must them all remove while using the class/method in an extended way. It feels a bit as written by a *smart alec* if we find *final* in the code. And often the author of the code can't know that the method is really the final one :-) Our coding standards contain a *don't use* flag for final. I personal think that final is often more wrong than a goto!

Comment: You may try to find if a static analyzer tool can enforce this requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C++11 standard, you are explicitly not allowed to do so for functions. The relevant passage is under § 9.2/8:

> A *virt-specifier-seq* shall contain at most one of each *virt-specifier*. A *virt-specifier-seq* shall appear only in the declaration of a virtual member function (10.3).

A *virt-specifier* includes `final` and `override`.

My guess is that they thought that these specifiers didn't make sense to be used in non-virtual functions since non-virtual functions are `final` by default and they are the "final overrider" as the standard states in other sections.

> It looks like this means I have to declare all methods as virtual now to be able to do that. Is that a good idea or are there reasons against it?

I recommend against it -- as having virtual functions has different effects on the code which you may not want. For example, the class will now have to keep a vtable and lose its POD status. Overall it seems like a bad move if you just want to use the `final` keyword.

Comment: A `virtual final` method that doesn't override has no reasonable reason to have a vtable; I expect most implementations will drop the ball and still have one.  (Sadly, there isn't a `new` keyword that states this method does not override, otherwise `virtual final new` would be an amusing way to guarantee non-virtual behavior on a call to a method)